# Prefix has no namespace binding Error while using transform module in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I am using transform module to change the document uri of files while doing mlcp ingestion.

But I am getting below error -

```
23/01/13 15:10:37 INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
23/01/13 15:10:38 ERROR contentpump.TransformWriter: Batch 361007023.0: Document failed permanently: /opt/mlcp-10.0.9-bin/mlcp-10.0.9/bin/data/EDI_22000041.xml
23/01/13 15:10:38 WARN contentpump.TransformWriter: <error:format-string xmlns:error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">XDMP-UNBPRFX: (err:XPST0081) Prefix doc has no namespace binding</error:format-string>
23/01/13 15:10:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 100%
23/01/13 15:10:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: com.marklogic.mapreduce.MarkLogicCounter:
23/01/13 15:10:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: INPUT_RECORDS: 1
23/01/13 15:10:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS: 1
23/01/13 15:10:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS_COMMITTED: 0
23/01/13 15:10:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS_FAILED: 1
```

This is the transform module -

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace doc = "http://marklogic.com/example";

declare function doc:uri(
  $content as map:map,
  $context as map:map
) as map:map*
{
  let $changeduri := map:get($content, "value")/EDILogFile/DateCreated
  return
    (
      map:put(
          $content, "/EDI"||"_"||$changeduri||".xml")
    )
};
```

This is the custom xquery transformation

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:document-load("/opt/urichange.xqy",
    <options xmlns="xdmp:document-load">
      <uri>/opt/urichange.xqy</uri>
      <repair>none</repair>
      <permissions>{xdmp:default-permissions()}</permissions>
    </options>)
```

And this is the file which I am trying to ingest -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <EDILogFile xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///Projects/test/schema/LogFile.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ID>****</ID>
        <SystemRef>22000041</SystemRef>
        <DateCreated>2022-09-06T19:07:46.3492849+01:00</DateCreated>
        <TimeSaved>240</TimeSaved>
        <Production>true</Production>
        <Partner>test</Partner>
        <MessageType>test</MessageType>
        <Fail>false</Fail>
        <ManyReasons/>
        <SubmissionUser>test</SubmissionUser>
        <InternalBusinessUnit>test</InternalBusinessUnit>
        <Direction>Inbound</Direction>
    </EDILogFile>
```

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test and see if it's *the* problem, but one issue with the transform is that you aren't returning the `$content` map in your function.

Comment: and your map:put is missing the "uri" key param, should be: `map:put($content, "uri", "/EDI"||"_"||$changeduri||".xml")`

Comment: and you are *sure* that the namespace declaration for the `doc` namespace is in the transform module that you are executing?

Comment: I am getting a different error after adding the uri key param .  Below is the error I am getting

Comment: 23/01/16 09:33:00 INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
23/01/16 09:33:00 ERROR contentpump.TransformWriter: Batch 1262955607.0: Document failed permanently: /opt/mlcp-10.0.9-bin/mlcp-10.0.9/bin/data/EDI_22000041.xml
23/01/16 09:33:00 WARN contentpump.TransformWriter: <error:format-string xmlns:error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting Function30_ or Percent_</error:format-string>

Comment: I think there is something missing in my xquery ?

Comment: xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace doc = "http://marklogic.com/example";

declare function doc:uri(
  $content as map:map,
  $context as map:map
) as map:map*
{
  let $changeduri := map:get($content, "value")/Test/DateCreated
  return
    (
   map:put($content, "uri", "/EDI"||"_"||$changeduri||".xml")
    )
};

Comment: @madshansen :I have resolved the return thing and changed the query a bit. Now I am getting some string typecast error . arg3 is not of type node() due to string typecast error. I have opened a new question on that as this is related to typecast error. Can you please check and give some suggestion.